# Virtualized Resources Dynamic Zoning

Tags: virtualization, hypervisor

I have a question regarding the dynamic zoning for resources assigned to Virtual machines, is there anyway to dynamically control the resources assigned for Virtual machines whatever is the hypervisor, I want to know what things needed to be considered if I am having different load time during the day so the VM should response to this variation at same time, if the customer asks for doubling the assigned resources for his/her VM there should something guarantees that the bandwidth or whatever the assigned resources will be doubled according to the request.

Can anybody explain to me which hypervisor implement this as my knowledge this is isn't possible in the current Opensource hypervisors xen, kvm, vbox,... etc, as I never worked with any commercial hypervisor before?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

did you check about [cgroups](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/cgroups.txt)? I am not sure about guarantee, but they can help you to expand resources whenever you need them through resource controllers.

Comment: in this case you assume I use linux in addition I am not sure they will help or not, BTW I use barrelfish OS